# Best practice for defining global variables/enums in Sails.JS?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I'm using helpers/log.js to manage all my console logs and I want to define a LogTypes enum so that it can be accessed from any controller or model when logged.

```
// Usage
await log('info', util.format('Attempting to create a new user with UserId: %s', req.body.userId));

// helpers/log.js
var moment = require("moment");
var util = require("util");
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Log',
  description: 'Log something.',

  inputs: {
      logType:{
      type: 'string',
      isIn: ['info', 'warn', 'err'],
      defaultsTo:  'info'
    },
    message: {
      friendlyName: 'Log message',
      description: 'The log message to output to the console.',
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    }
  },
  exits: {

  },
  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    sails.log(util.format('%s: %s: %s', moment(), inputs.logType, 
inputs.message));
    // All done.
    return exits.success();
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you looked into `captains-log` ? https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/logging

Comment: Yep I have, johnabrams7. Long story short I need to know the best practise around defining global variables in sails. Such as an enum to be used as a log type.